# Cloudera Manager CDH5 - Installation Failure on Oozie Database

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

While doing the installation, i keep getting a failure on the step "Creating Oozie database"

```
java.lang.Exception: DB schema exists
    at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.validateDBSchema(OozieDBCLI.java:877)
    at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.createDB(OozieDBCLI.java:184)
    at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.run(OozieDBCLI.java:127)
    at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.main(OozieDBCLI.java:78)
```

How do i fix this? Where do i get the password/username/dbname for the PostgreSQL database to drop the existing schema?

I tried 
cat /etc/cloudera-scm-server/db*.properties | grep pass

and

/var/lib/cloudera-scm-server-db/data/generated-password.txt

but the passwords don't work!

Comment: I eventually connected to the PostgreSQL database using the following command

psql -h localhost -U cloudera-scm -p 7432 -d scm

using the password from the generated_passwords.txt file

Answer (score 1):

### For future visitors :

Cloudera creates aliases and alternatives to the path where it installs parcels.

Oozie Configs resides at `/etc/oozie/conf/`

To view and edit database configurations, visit : `/etc/oozie/conf/oozie-site.xml` and look for `jdbc`.

In ubuntu based systems, oozie keeps data in `/var/lib/oozie/data/`

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem. It may be because I used to install Hue before. I solved this by deleting the contents of /var/lib/oozie/:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/oozie/*
```

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to execute command Create Database on service Oozie

`rm -rf /var/lib/oozie/*`
Then retry first run.
Helped to fix the issue, service started.